What is the difference between AddItem and createOrReplaceInventoryItem API call in ebay API service
What is the difference between AddItem and createOrReplaceInventoryItem API call in ebay API service.
Secondly, if I create a inventory item then create the offer and publish it in UK marketplace and then from the same account want to make upload the product for lets say US marketplace so the itemID returned from eBay in both cases would be different?
